# Using item in Ansible json_query

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath

I'm trying to loop through a list of keys to grab associated names from some json:

```yaml
- name: show names
  debug:
    msg: "{{ data.json | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[? key==item].name"
  with_items: "{{ keys.split() }}"
```

But it never displays properly when I try to run it. The keys are correct, but no data is returned:

```
TASK [get_help_on_SO: show] 
ok: [localhost] => (item=Key1) => {
    "msg": []
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Key2) => {
    "msg": []
}
```

Manually putting in the code works just fine so my query syntax seems to be right:

```
query: "[? key==`Key1`].name"

TASK [get_help_on_SO : show] 
ok: [localhost] => (item=Key1) => {
    "msg": [
        "FooBar 1"
]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=Key2) => {
    "msg": [
        "FooBar 1"
    ]
}
```

How can I properly pass the `item` into the `json_query`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't surround the `item` variable with any Jinja delimiters, so it is not interpreted.
You end testing if the `key` is equal to the string `'item'` and not to the string stored in the variable `item`.

```yaml
- name: show names
  debug:
    msg: "{{ data.json | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query: "[?key==`{{ item }}`].name"
  with_items: "{{ keys.split() }}"
```

Comment: Wonderful thanks! It works! I was playing with the JMESPath Syntax and it seemed like the backticks were for string literals. I guess I have two more questions: 1. Why don't I put the {{ }} on the outside of the query variable. 2. Why can't I just paste the value of query into the json_query()?

Answer (score 2):

Given the data

```yaml
    keys: 'key1 key3'
    data:
      json: [{
            "key": "key1",
            "name": "name1"
            },
            {
            "key": "key2",
            "name": "name2"
            },
            {
            "key": "key3",
            "name": "name3"
            }
            ]
```

the expected result is

```yaml
  - name1
  - name3
```

It's possible to avoid both the *loop* and *json_query* and simplify the solution. The task below

```yaml
    - name: show names
      debug:
        msg: "{{ data.json|
                 selectattr('key', 'in', my_keys)|
                 map(attribute='name')|
                 list }}"
      vars:
        my_keys: "{{ keys.split() }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
  - name1
  - name3
```